# cx_Freeze - Error when running .exe from desktop shortcut

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

My Pygame app runs perfectly from the `.exe` file after being compiled as an `msi` in cx_Freeze, but when I run it from the desktop shortcut, I get an error:

[image]

The shortcut Target is correct, the sound files are all in the right directory, I have tried both `.wav` and `.ogg` files and reduced the bitrate etc, but nothing seems to work. The frustrating thing is, it runs perfectly when I open the target location and run the `.exe` manually. I cannot figure out why the desktop shortcut method is causing an error.

Here is my `setup.py` file:

```
import sys
import cx_Freeze

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable(
    script="a_bit_racey.py",
    base=base,
    icon="car_icon.ico",
    shortcutName="A bit Racey",
    shortcutDir="DesktopFolder")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="A bit Racey",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages": ["pygame"],
                           "include_files": ["racecar.png", "Crash.ogg", "Ecstasy_X.ogg",
                                             "car_icon.ico"]}},
    executables=executables
)
```

Am I missing an msi property that the shortcut needs? I've been stuck on this for a week.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot that might better explain, as I'm getting very little response:

[image]

The desktop shortcut that was created with cx_Freeze has the correct target location, and even seems to run the `.exe` file, but then errors. Yet, when I open the target location and double-click the `.exe` file, it works perfectly!!

Comment: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#data-files

Please ensure that absolute paths are being used under the hood, like this cx_Freeze doc seems to lead me to believe. Obviously in the `"include_files"` list these are relative. Do you have a data_dir finding f(x)?

Comment: @seanmus: Yes, all data files are named correctly in the "include_files" statement as part of the build setup script. I don't know what you mean by f(x). Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: in the section called  "Using data files", do you have a function resembling the one provided in docs?

Comment: The reason the exe runs fine from the folder is because of the working directory. The reason the shortcut doesn't is for the same reason.

Comment: @seanmus: I have an apology to make - it took some tweaking, and I had to figure out where to call the code, but your original comment was spot on. Please add it as the Answer and I'll rate it up. I'll also add a comment to explain what I did to make it work because there's very little anywhere on the internet about it. THANK YOU!

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the follow up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#data-files

Please ensure that absolute paths are being used under the hood, like this cx_Freeze doc seems to lead me to believe. Obviously in the "include_files" list these are relative. Do you have a data_dir finding function? If not look in the docs for the "Using data files" section.

Comment: Additional info: Put the `find_data_file` function into your main `.py` file (not the setup file). You will need to add `import os` at the top. And here's an example of how to call the function for each data file you need to load (applies to sound files, music, images etc):

First, declare a variable for the filepath:
`racecar_path = find_data_file("racecar.png")`

and then change your load statement to:
`car_img = pygame.image.load(racecar_path)`

Do the same for each data file, and after your `.msi` file has been built with cx_Freeze, it will install and run correctly!