# Tkinter exe made from cx_Freeze cannot find png file in shortcut folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have made a simple Tkinter App in virtual environment

**main.py**

```py
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage
from sys import platform
import os


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("100x100")
    ICO_FILE = os.path.join("images/icon.png")

    BITMAP_IMG = PhotoImage(file=ICO_FILE)
    root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, BITMAP_IMG)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Jai Swaminarayan")
    main()
```

I converted it to installer using cx_freeze

**setup.py**

```py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

##### Added Code Starts ######
def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)
##### Added Code Ends ######

includefiles = ["images/"]
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": [], "include_files": includefiles}
base = None

if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"


setup(
    name = "Test",
    url='https://github.com/ajinzrathod/',
    version = "1.0.0", 
    description = "Swaminarayan",
    options = {
        "build_exe": build_exe_options,
        "bdist_msi": {
            'install_icon': r"images/icon.ico",
            }
        },
    executables = [
        Executable("main.py",
             base=base,
             icon=r"images/icon.ico",
             shortcut_name='Test',
             shortcut_dir='DesktopFolder',
             )
        ]
    )
```

**Created an MSI installer**

```
> python setup.py bdist_msi
```

This works perfectly when I run the application in installed directory which is `C:\Users\Ajinkya Rathod\AppData\Local\Programs\Test\main.exe`

**The main problem is here. I have also created a Desktop shortcut. When I open my app from desktop, it shows:**

```
ERROR: icon.png file not found
```

Application is searching for images in Desktop Folder. Whereas it should search in Installed Directory. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951101/cx-freeze-error-when-running-exe-from-desktop-shortcut) has the same kind of error and as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078806/11605100), I saw the documentation at [this link](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#data-files) and added the code in ***setup.py***

But still unable to solve the issue. Trying since long time. Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `find_data_file()` function is used in the application script, not `setup.py`.

Comment: @acw1668 You mean in **main.py**? And how should I call that function?

Comment: Thanks, @acw1668 Worked like a charm. Still, my app is not visible in Application Launcher. Any ideas?